# How to only get one variable when applying a function

Tags: r, apply

I have a data table that I want to apply a function over namely the `historical_exchange rates` function from `priceR`. I have figured out how to apply this function across my data table however the function spits out two variables. I only want to get the specific exchange rate from the function. So that in the column `Par_value_EUR` I get the exchange rate on the issuance date. For the first row, this would be 0.108031

My data table looks as follows:

```
         ISIN    TR.FiCurrency TR.FiIssueDate Par_value_EUR
1: XS1231261907           SEK     2015-05-12            NA
2: XS1231286995           EUR     2015-05-12            NA
3: XS1231416287           HKD     2015-05-19            NA
4: XS1232143310           EUR     2015-05-13            NA
5: XS1232309226           HKD     2015-05-20            NA
6: XS1232498011           USD     2015-05-27            NA

structure(list(ISIN = c("XS1231261907", "XS1231286995", "XS1231416287", 
"XS1232143310", "XS1232309226", "XS1232498011"), TR.FiCurrency = c("SEK", 
"EUR", "HKD", "EUR", "HKD", "USD"), TR.FiIssueDate = structure(c(16567, 
16567, 16574, 16568, 16575, 16582), class = "Date"), Par_value_EUR = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fc85800cee0>)
```

I'm applying this function across rows in my data table using apply:

```
par_values_test$Par_value_EUR <- apply(par_values_test[,c('TR.FiCurrency','TR.FiIssueDate')], 1, 
                                       function(y) historical_exchange_rates(y['TR.FiCurrency'], "EUR", y['TR.FiIssueDate'],y['TR.FiIssueDate'] ) )
```

The result is as follows:

```
           ISIN TR.FiCurrency TR.FiIssueDate     Par_value_EUR
1: XS1231261907           SEK     2015-05-12 <data.frame[1x2]>
2: XS1231286995           EUR     2015-05-12 <data.frame[1x2]>
3: XS1231416287           HKD     2015-05-19 <data.frame[1x2]>
4: XS1232143310           EUR     2015-05-13 <data.frame[1x2]>
5: XS1232309226           HKD     2015-05-20 <data.frame[1x2]>
6: XS1232498011           USD     2015-05-27 <data.frame[1x2]>
```

As you can see this puts a new data frame in the column `Par_value_EUR` and I only want the second element from this data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could extract the column with `[[`.  In addition, it may be better to use `lapply/Map` instead of `apply` as `apply` converts to `matrix` and matrix can have only a single type

```
library(data.table)
library(priceR)
par_values_test[, Par_value_EUR := 
     unlist(Map(function(x, y) 
       tryCatch(historical_exchange_rates(x, "EUR", y, y),
     error = function(e) data.frame(col1 = NA_real_, col2 = NA_real_))[[2]],
        TR.FiCurrency, TR.FiIssueDate))]
```

-output

```
> par_values_test
           ISIN TR.FiCurrency TR.FiIssueDate Par_value_EUR
         <char>        <char>         <Date>         <num>
1: XS1231261907           SEK     2015-05-12      0.108031
2: XS1231286995           EUR     2015-05-12      1.000000
3: XS1231416287           HKD     2015-05-19      0.113934
4: XS1232143310           EUR     2015-05-13      1.000000
5: XS1232309226           HKD     2015-05-20      0.115770
6: XS1232498011           USD     2015-05-27      0.918358
```

Comment: For some currencies e.g. ATS, the `hirstorical_exchange_rates` function returns NULL which makes this solution fail. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @EliasK. just add the `[1]` at the end (updated) after appending with `NA` at the end.  Thus, if there are NULL elements, the first element with `NA` or else the value i.e. `c(NULL, NA)[1]#
[1] NA`

Comment: I keep getting the following error 'Error in `stop_bad_type()`:
! Result 1 must be a single double, not NULL of length 0' when running on this test data `structure(list(ISIN = c("AT0000134929", "AT0000134937", "AT0000134978", 
"AT0000134986", "AT0000272505"), TR.FiCurrency = c("ATS", "ATS", 
"ATS", "ATS", "ATS"), TR.FiIssueDate = structure(c(10037, 10263, 
10779, 10779, 10057), class = "Date"), Par_value_EUR = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fc85800cee0>)`

Comment: @EliasK. i understand the issue, but I think it may be better to use `tryCatch` (updated) it now works with your new example as well

Comment: I guess this is just because the `historical_exchange_rates`function returns Null for both vectors and why the first method didn't work? Thank you very much for the answer the try catch works!

Comment: @EliasK. Actually, the error is coming from within the `historical_exchange_rates` itself when it tries to call `pmap_dbl` i.e. `Map(function(x, y) historical_exchange_rates(x, "EUR", y, y), par_values_test2$TR.FiCurrency, par_values_test2$TR.FiIssueDate)` after `debugonce(historical_exchange_rates)`, then `debug: pmap_dfr(api_time_splits, retrieve_historical_rates, from = from, 
    to = to)
Browse[2]> 
Error in `stop_bad_type()`:`

Comment: So, I guess the `tryCatch` is better suited for this

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the second value from the historical_exchange_rates function, you can add a bracket to indicate the indices that you would like returned. See the "[2]" at the very end of the command.

```
par_values_test$Par_value_EUR <- apply(par_values_test[,c('TR.FiCurrency','TR.FiIssueDate')], 1, 
                                       function(y) historical_exchange_rates(y['TR.FiCurrency'], "EUR", y['TR.FiIssueDate'],y['TR.FiIssueDate'] )[2] )
```

Comment: This is the route I was looking into using - however, I think you need to unlist() the second variable or use the second variable's name so the output has the value rather than the nested table in the output.

Comment: apply(par_values_test[, c('TR.FiCurrency', 'TR.FiIssueDate')], 1,
             function(y)
               unlist(priceR::historical_exchange_rates(y['TR.FiCurrency'], "EUR", y['TR.FiIssueDate'], y['TR.FiIssueDate'])[2]))